# _int_() missing 1 required positional argument: on_delete

Tags: python, django, django-models

Anyone please help solve this error, I am creating library book app

[image: Anyone please help solve this error, I am creating library book app]

Comment: As for the error, you made a typo: it is `on_delete`, not `on_delet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have `on_delete`. You have `on_delet`. Fix this and should be fine